# Regarding Object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json

How to loop through an array of object got similar key and different value for Example if,

```
arrayOfObjects = [
{ parent: 'relatedParty', child: 'role === CEO', andOr = '&&' }
{ parent: 'relatedParty', child: 'name === Arun' , andOr = '||'}
{ parent: 'relatedParty', child: ' id === 123', andOr = '&&' }
{ parent: 'cusotm', child: 'contact === DAP', andOr = '||' }
{ parent: 'custom', child: 'team==dap', andOr = '&&' }
{ parent: 'multiple', child: 'key ===keys', andOr = '||' }
{ parent: 'multiple', child: 'value=== values', andOr = '&&' }
].
```

im stuck in a position where how can i iterate through this and get output like if
first object of parent is ===  second object, then I want them to add into an array and finally those values should be inside another array

```
[[role === CEO && name === Arun && id === 123 &&], [contact === DAP || team==dap && ],[ key ===keys || value=== values &&]]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example is not a valid array, are you getting it from somewhere else, like a http request?

Anyway, after fixing it to a valid array, you can try grouping by parent, and them mapping the values into what you need.

Grouping could be like:

```js
const grouped = {}
arrayOfObjects.forEach(obj => {
  if (!grouped[obj.parent]) {
    grouped[obj.parent] = []
  }
  grouped[obj.parent].push(obj)
})
```

You can also use reduce, or other ways to group by parent.

After it, just map the values into what you want:

```js
const result = Object.values(grouped).map(group => {
  return group.map(obj => `${obj.child} ${obj.andOr}`).join(' ')
})
```

If you need it in string format to send to some api, do it like:

```js
const body = JSON.stringify(result)
```

Comment: How it is not a valid array

Comment: It does not have commas between its elements, seems like you copy and pasted each of them from somewhere else... if you try to run your sampled array, you will get an error

Answer (score 0):

Here is a more concise way to handle your problem:

```
const arrayOfString = arrayOfObjects.reduce((acc, {parent, child, andOr}) => {
    const value = `${child} ${andOr}`
  acc[parent] = acc[parent] ? [`${acc[parent] || ''} ${value}`] : [`${value}`]
    return acc
},  {})

const result = Array.from(Object.values(arrayOfString))
```